# Add object value to score based on propety name

Tags: javascript, arrays, oop

I am trying to add the value of an object based on the propery name. I have created a quiz and assigned an answer score to each choice (property name). I need to add choices.score to this.score. For example if they select Happy, add 6 to this.score

Everything else is working correctly, I just can't figure out how to add the object value to the score when the choice is selected.

```js
function Quiz(questions) {
    this.score = 0;
    this.questions = questions;
    this.questionIndex = 0;
}
 
Quiz.prototype.getQuestionIndex = function() {
    return this.questions[this.questionIndex];
}
 
Quiz.prototype.guess = function(answer) {

        this.score++ ; //HERE IS WHERE I NEED TO ADD THE SCORE FROM THE SELECTED CHOICE
// I would like it to be this.score + choice.score but cant figure it out
        this.questionIndex++;
}
 
Quiz.prototype.isEnded = function() {
    return this.questionIndex === this.questions.length;
}
 
 
function Question(text, choices, score,both) {
    this.text = text;
    this.choices = Object.keys(choices);
    this.score = Object.values(choices);
    this.both = Object.entries(choices);
}

Question.prototype.isCorrectAnswer = function(choice) {
    return this.answer === choice;
}
 
 
function populate() {
    if(quiz.isEnded()) {
        showScores();
    }
    else {
        // show question
        var element = document.getElementById("question");
        element.innerHTML = quiz.getQuestionIndex().text;
 
        // show options
        var choices = quiz.getQuestionIndex().choices;
        for(var i = 0; i < choices.length; i++) {
            var element = document.getElementById("choice" + i);
            element.innerHTML = choices[i];
            guess("btn" + i, choices[i]);
        }
 
        showProgress();
    }
};


function guess(id, guess) {
    var button = document.getElementById(id);
    button.onclick = function() {
        quiz.guess(guess);
        populate();
    }
};
 
 
function showProgress() {
    var currentQuestionNumber = quiz.questionIndex + 1;
    var element = document.getElementById("progress");
    element.innerHTML = "Question " + currentQuestionNumber + " of " + quiz.questions.length;
};
 
function showScores() {
    var gameOverHTML = "<h1>Result</h1>";
    gameOverHTML += "<h2 id='score'> Your scores: " + quiz.score + "</h2>";
    var element = document.getElementById("quiz");
    element.innerHTML = gameOverHTML;
};
 
// create questions here
var questions = [
    new Question("How are you feeling today?",{'very sad': "1", 'sad':"3",'happy':"6", 'very happy':"9"}),
    new Question("How angry are you today?",{'very angry': "1", 'little angry':"3",'not angry':"6", 'very happy':"9"})
];
console.log(questions);
// create quiz
var quiz = new Quiz(questions);
 
// display quiz
populate();
```

```html
 <div class="grid">
        <div id="quiz">
            <h1>Self Assessment</h1>
            <hr style="margin-bottom: 20px">

            <p id="question"></p>
 
            <div class="buttons">
                <button id="btn0"><span id="choice0"></span></button>
                <button id="btn1"><span id="choice1"></span></button>
                <button id="btn2"><span id="choice2"></span></button>
                <button id="btn3"><span id="choice3"></span></button>
            </div>
            <hr style="margin-top: 50px">
            <footer>
                <p id="progress">Question x of y</p>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: what is in this.score ? it seems u have object values

Comment: this.score starts out at 0, but I need to add the score value from the Question Object. For example : new Question("How are you feeling today?",{'very sad': "1", 'sad':"3",'happy':"6", 'very happy':"9"}) If they select sad, I add 3 to this.score

Comment: i will recommend move the score out of the quize.

Comment: can u add basic HTM to run it

Comment: I added the HTML to bottom of my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at your code.. i try to find solution.. please refer to below answer:

Instead of converting in key values separate array, u can key in the same array. so that key will be text to show and the value will be the score. when the user will choose to send both and get the answer.

Working sample:

```js
function Quiz(questions) {
  this.score = 0;
  this.questions = questions;
  this.questionIndex = 0;
}

Quiz.prototype.getQuestionIndex = function () {
  return this.questions[this.questionIndex];
};

Quiz.prototype.guess = function (answer) {
  this.score += Number(answer[1]);

  this.questionIndex++;
};

Quiz.prototype.isEnded = function () {
  return this.questionIndex === this.questions.length;
};

function Question(text, choices, score, both) {
  this.text = text;
  this.choices = Object.entries(choices);
  this.both = Object.entries(choices);
}

Question.prototype.isCorrectAnswer = function (choice) {
  return this.answer === choice;
};

function populate() {
  if (quiz.isEnded()) {
    showScores();
  } else {
    // show question
    var element = document.getElementById("question");
    element.innerHTML = quiz.getQuestionIndex().text;

    // show options
    const question = quiz.getQuestionIndex(); /// this line
    //console.log(question)
    var choices = question.choices;
    for (var i = 0; i < choices.length; i++) {
      var element = document.getElementById("choice" + i);
      element.innerHTML = choices[i][0];
      guess("btn" + i, choices[i]); /// this line
    }

    showProgress();
  }
}

function guess(id, guess) {
  var button = document.getElementById(id);
  button.onclick = function () {
    quiz.guess(guess); /// this line
    populate();
  };
}

function showProgress() {
  var currentQuestionNumber = quiz.questionIndex + 1;
  var element = document.getElementById("progress");
  element.innerHTML =
    "Question " + currentQuestionNumber + " of " + quiz.questions.length;
}

function showScores() {
  var gameOverHTML = "<h1>Result</h1>";
  gameOverHTML += "<h2 id='score'> Your scores: " + quiz.score + "</h2>";
  var element = document.getElementById("quiz");
  element.innerHTML = gameOverHTML;
}

// create questions here
var questions = [
  new Question("How are you feeling today?", {
    "very sad": "1",
    sad: "3",
    happy: "6",
    "very happy": "9",
  }),
  new Question("How angry are you today?", {
    "very angry": "1",
    "little angry": "3",
    "not angry": "6",
    "very happy": "9",
  }),
];
// console.log(questions);
// create quiz
var quiz = new Quiz(questions);

// display quiz
populate();
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div id="quiz">
    <h1>Self Assessment</h1>
    <hr style="margin-bottom: 20px">

    <p id="question"></p>

    <div class="buttons">
      <button id="btn0"><span id="choice0"></span></button>
      <button id="btn1"><span id="choice1"></span></button>
      <button id="btn2"><span id="choice2"></span></button>
      <button id="btn3"><span id="choice3"></span></button>
    </div>
    <hr style="margin-top: 50px">
    <footer>
      <p id="progress">Question x of y</p>
    </footer>
  </div>
</div>
```

ES6:

```js
class Quiz {
  constructor(questions) {
    this.score = 0;
    this.questions = questions;
    this.questionIndex = 0;
  }

  getQuestionIndex() {
    return this.questions[this.questionIndex];
  }

  guess(answer) {
    this.score += Number(answer[1]);

    this.questionIndex++;
  }
  isEnded() {
    return this.questionIndex === this.questions.length;
  }
  populate() {
    if (quiz.isEnded()) {
      this.showScores();
    } else {
      // show question
      const element = document.getElementById("question");
      element.innerHTML = quiz.getQuestionIndex().text;

      // show options
      const question = quiz.getQuestionIndex(); /// this line
      //console.log(question)
      const choices = question.choices;
      choices.forEach((choice, i) => {
        const element = document.getElementById(`choice${i}`);
        element.innerHTML = choice[0];
        const button = document.getElementById(`btn${i}`);
        button.onclick = () => {
          this.guess(choice); /// this line
          this.populate();
        };
      });
      this.showProgress();
    }
  }

  showProgress() {
    const currentQuestionNumber = quiz.questionIndex + 1;
    const element = document.getElementById("progress");
    element.innerHTML = `Question ${currentQuestionNumber} of ${quiz.questions.length}`;
  }

  showScores() {
    let gameOverHTML = "<h1>Result</h1>";
    gameOverHTML += `<h2 id='score'> Your scores: ${quiz.score}</h2>`;
    const element = document.getElementById("quiz");
    element.innerHTML = gameOverHTML;
  }
}

class Question {
  constructor(text, choices, score, both) {
    this.text = text;
    this.choices = Object.entries(choices);
    this.both = Object.entries(choices);
  }

  isCorrectAnswer(choice) {
    return this.answer === choice;
  }
}

// create questions here
const questions = [
  new Question("How are you feeling today?", {
    "very sad": "1",
    sad: "3",
    happy: "6",
    "very happy": "9",
  }),
  new Question("How angry are you today?", {
    "very angry": "1",
    "little angry": "3",
    "not angry": "6",
    "very happy": "9",
  }),
];
// console.log(questions);
// create quiz
const quiz = new Quiz(questions);

// display quiz
quiz.populate();
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div id="quiz">
      <h1>Self Assessment</h1>
      <hr style="margin-bottom: 20px">

      <p id="question"></p>

      <div class="buttons">
          <button id="btn0"><span id="choice0"></span></button>
          <button id="btn1"><span id="choice1"></span></button>
          <button id="btn2"><span id="choice2"></span></button>
          <button id="btn3"><span id="choice3"></span></button>
      </div>
      <hr style="margin-top: 50px">
      <footer>
          <p id="progress">Question x of y</p>
      </footer>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I get:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'choices' of undefined
    at Quiz.guess (questions.js:12)
    at HTMLButtonElement.button.onclick (questions.js:60)
Line 12 is ``const score = question.choices[answer] /// this line``

Comment: i have added suggestion read it.. very complex way you did. try to keep OOPs pattern

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am struggling with Javascript. PHP is much easier for me

Comment: i have added ES6 version, u can check out second sample